# A .NET Framework error occurred during - error 6522 - while deploying SSIS

Tags: deployment, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have a SQL server 2019 and a visual studio 2019. I am the sysadmin and have created SSISDB through SSMS with some folders. I have also created a SSIS project in VS 2019.
If i execute the visual studio package from Visual studio it successfully runs and values populate the corresponding table.
However if I try to deploy the same project to the sql server, I am getting this

```
===================================

 

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "deploy_project_internal": 

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A required privilege is not held by the client

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerProcess.StartProcess(Boolean bSuspendThread)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.DeployProjectInternal(SqlInt64 deployId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 projectId, SqlString projectName)

. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

 

------------------------------

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-6522-database-engine-error

 

------------------------------

Server Name: 10.116.133.36

Error Number: 6522

Severity: 16

State: 1

Procedure: internal.deploy_project_internal

 



------------------------------

Program Location:

 

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel.SqlHelper.ExecuteSQLCommand(SqlStoreConnection storeConnection, CommandType cmdType, String cmdText, SqlParameter[] parameters, ExecuteType execType, Int32 commandTimeout)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder.DeployProject(String projectName, Byte[] projectStream)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeployExportProjectHelper.DeployProject(CatalogFolder folder, Project project)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeploymentModel.Deploy(CatalogFolder folder, Project project)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeploymentModel.DeployProject()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Deployment.DeployProjectPage.DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)

   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

 




MSSQLSERVER_6522 - SQL Server




MSSQLSERVER_6522
```

I did some research and made some adjustments but I am still unable to bypass this error.

I am already part of the SSIS_admin group and I followed the steps here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g5edCOVbYs

to fix the issue but the issue is still happening.

Can someone help please if you have came across a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Start" menu and navigate to: Settings > Windows Security.

Look for the Developer Mode section and ensure it is checked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP3mk.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).